# Which css rule, makes elements to be positioned vertically, despite inline-block rule?

Tags: html, css

Which css rule, makes elements to be positioned vertically, despite inline-block rule?

I want elements to inline horizontally, but instead they inline for me vertically.
Finally, i am not able to past all the css, because stackoverflow blocks the question code amount for me.

If i try on fiddle - they align horizontally, 
https://jsfiddle.net/j3e76u0L/1/
but if i try on my computer Opera, Chrome and Firefox browsers - they make a column of buttons instead of a row;
and if i load from remote server , where i have subscription, - buttons also make a column instead of a row .

html

```
<button class="inbk" type="submit" name="redirLogin">Login</button>
<button class="inbk" type="submit" name="redirRegister">Register</button>
<button class="inbk" type="submit" name="redirRemind">Remind</button>
<button class="inbk" type="submit" name="redirContact">Contact</button>
```

css

```
.inbk {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom; /* tried with this and without this, both cases smth in css makes buttons align vertically, instead of beein inline */
}
```

If i put only this css + colors and text - buttons are aligned horizontally,

but if i put this css at the end of the whole sylesheet (which is enclosed below), the rules does not make buttons with class `.inbk` to align horizontally. Smth affects their alignment, and i do not understand what. I can nto show this on Fiddle, because buttons align horizontally there. But on my screen they form a vertical column of buttons in Firefix, Opera and Chrome.

The full css :

```
/* reset */

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
input,
select,
option,
button,
textarea,
checkbox,
.ckSq4 h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video,
footer,
footer span,
footer span a .backTx,
.stPta,
.stUi,
.txcopy,
.c100,
.txtTyp,
.butt,
.bodyCt {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/*  *, *:before, *:after {
      box-sizing: inherit; } */

body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font-size: 32px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
}

.bodyCt {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.c100 {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  clear: both;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
}

footer {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  outline: none !important;
}

footer,
footer span,
footer span a {
  height: 32px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

span {
  display: inline;
}

button,
.btn,
input {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}


.inbk {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.ctTypPlatformSet:before,
.ctTypPlatformSet:after,
ctTypOutest:before,
ctTypOutest:after,
.typSetInfo:before,
.typSetInfo:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.ctTypPlatformSet:after,
ctTypOutest:after,
.typSetInfo:after {
  clear: both;
}

option {
  top: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  /* height: 51.2px; */
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  /* (padding: [top/bottom] [left/right]  */
  text-align: center;
}

.butSTART {
  width: 384px;
  padding: 0 px;
  text-align: center;
}

.ct {
  top: 0px;
  height: auto;
}

.ctTypOutest {
  top: 0px;
  height: 515.84px;
}


/*  Part1 of TypFormProtFnc, start button and timer  */

.startButElAdd {
  top: 0px;
  height: 112.64px;
}


/*  Part2 of TypFormProtFnc  */

.finger {
  top: 112.64px;
  height: 67.2px;
}


/*  Part3 of TypFormProtFnc  also  */

.userProgWrap,
.ctExType {
  top: 179.84px;
  height: 336px;
}


/*  Part3 of TypFormProtFnc contains the following elements insise */


/* ctTxt */


/* ctTypOutest */


/* .stPta : textArea of Part3 TypFormProtFnc  */


/* .stUi : user input of Part3 TypFormProtFnc  */


/* .backTx :  div with txcopy of Part3 TypFormProtFnc  */


/* .txcopy :  div with styled copy of user input of Part3 TypFormProtFnc  */

.stUi,
.stPta,
.backTx,
.txcopy {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.stUi {
  height: 80px;
}

.stPta,
.backTx,
.txcopy {
  height: 336px;
}

.ctLett,
.stPta,
.stUi,
.backTx,
.ctTxt,
.finger,
.startButElAdd {
  width: 1200px;
}

.stPta,
.stUi,
.backTx,
.finger {
  overfow: hidden;
}

table,
th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 4.8px;
}

p,
div,
span,
a {
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 32px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: normal;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

p {
  text-indent: 48px;
}

.chMenuC,
.btn,
.startButEl {
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 3.2px;
  text-indent: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 51.2px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: normal;
  text-indent: 0px;
}

div,
span,
.chMenuC,
.btn,
.startButEl,
select,
select option,
option {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: normal;
  text-align: justify;
}

div,
span,
.chMenuC,
.btn,
option,
.startButEl {
  text-indent: 48px;
}

select option {
  font-size: 32px;
}

select {
  font-size: 32px;
  text-indent: 2px;
}

.txtTyp {
  text-align: left;
}

.finger,
.txtTyp,
.infoStr {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  text-indent: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 80px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: normal;
  color: #9233db;
}

footer,
footer span,
footer span a {
  font-size: 25.6px;
  text-indent: 0px;
  line-height: 25.6px;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, fantasy;
  color: #52009e;
}

footer,
footer span,
footer span a {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  outline: none !important;
}


/*scrolling*/

.backTx,
.txcopy {
  overflow: auto;
}

footer {
  background-color: #bbd9ed;
}

.backTx {
  background-color: rgba(215, 220, 254, 0.5);
  color: rgba(233, 43, 233, 0.9);
}

.txcopy {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.stPta {
  color: rgba(0, 55, 184, 0.94);
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: none;
}

.stUi {
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.err,
err {
  color: rgba(253, 48, 48, 0.5);
  background-color: rgba(255, 173, 173, 0.5);
}

.correct,
correct {
  color: #1ca01f;
  background-color: #97ed98;
}

wrong {
  color: #77ff0f;
  background-color: #ff0f0f;
}

.btn,
button,
input[type=submit] {
  border: 2px solid #6c74e5;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #cacafc;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b8a4ef, #ddd4f7);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.btn:hover,
button :hover {
  background-color: #a3b4ff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b8a4ef, #f9e2f6);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0000fe;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want.
You want to the buttons to be inline or you want a "return" between each ?

Comment: You have no rule in your question which does that. You need to create a real [mcve]

Comment: look at the result of your snippet - they align horzontally, not vertically...

Comment: in my application they align vertically. This is the only code i include and i check on Opera, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Seems the reason is how i output the files. I use own mini-framework, and it makes smth to stylesheets, that they got included in the `body`, instead of the `head`. If i do not use `View` or `Controller` to dispay `test.php`, the styles works and i can see them in `head` part. But if try to output `test.php` from view or `Controller` action, styles does not work properly and are included to the `body` part.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110643/move-style-from-php-to-head  - seems helpfull

Comment: The reason for this behaviour was misplaced meta tags, they were not in the `head`, but in the `body` instead. The `<span>` inside `head`, like  `<head><span id="styles1" class="styles"> <link .... /> </span></head>`  gives errors, about missing `head`, and misplaced `body`. If you need javascript apply to head, put `class` and `id` inside `link`, do not create wrapping span for this.

Comment: The reason for this behaviour was misplaced meta tags, they were not in the `head`, but in the `body` instead. I  have removed all `print_r`, and `echo` statements, which i have used fro debugging. After this, the `head` is in place, thus styles and meta tags are working.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons were vertical instead of horizontal, because

1) I had misplaced meta tags and styles, they were not in the head, but in the body instead.

Styles tags were in the body, thus they were applied not in right order. Styles were in the body, because i use own mini-mvc, where output flushing is affected by `print_r` and `echo`

```
ob_start();
$viewData = $this->data; 
include_once( $this->viewTemplPath.$this->file ); //if included files have print_r or echo, the styles gets displaced.
if($store) { $buffer = ob_get_clean(); echo $buffer; }
else ob_end_flush();
```

I have removed all `print_r`, and `echo` statements, which i have used for debugging. After this, the head is in place, thus styles and meta tags are working.

2) I have also removed wrapping `<span>` inside head, like `<head><span id="styles1" class="styles"> <link .... /> </span></head>`, which gives errors, about missing head, and misplaced body. If you need javascript apply to head, put class and id inside link, do not create wrapping span for this.

3) Finally, analyzing the stylesheet i have found that commenting out the lines `word-wrap: break-word;` , and `white-space: pre-wrap;` makes buttons to be horizontal.

```
p, div, span, a {
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 32px;
  /* white-space: pre-wrap; */
  /* word-wrap: break-word; */
  word-break: normal; 
  text-indent: 0px;
```

}

My `buttons` are included in the template, where they are in `<div id="header">`. Most probably `break-word`, for the `div` contents = `the buttons`, makes them to go to separate lines.

Answer (score -1):

Use `float: [left/right];`, then for floated elements there is `clear: [both/left/right]`

```css
button {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<button class="inbk" type="submit" name="redirLogin" >Login</button>
<button class="inbk" type="submit" name="redirRegister" >Register</button>
<button class="inbk" type="submit" name="redirRemind" >Remind</button>
<button class="inbk" type="submit" name="redirContact" >Contact</button>
```

Comment: I need them to be inlined horiontally in the line. Normally, if one use inline-block ,the lements are aligned horizontally. But , in my case, i do not understand why, they got aligned vertically.

Comment: Either right-click on element and inspect it via console, or show relevant CSS rules. It may be that you have less space than needed and elements fall one after another

Comment: If they are in vertical column they take more space than in horizontal row. If i hcek the rules, i can see only text, colors, nothing related to alignment, except the rules i set  `display: inline-block;` and  `vertical-align: bottom;` ( i also tried without this rule) .

Comment: if i make a short styleshwwt for class `.inbk` at the end of stylesheet, hoping to overwrite all possible other rules, it does not work .I  need whole stylesheet to be loaded, because the buttons are part of header, and the whle stylesheet applies for whole project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110643/move-style-from-php-to-head  - seems helpfull