# What could be the reason that styles, after `ob_end_flush();` are included to the body, instead of the head part?

Tags: php, css, view, ob-start

What could be the reason that styles, after `ob_end_flush();` are included to the `body`, instead of the `head` part?

test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?php echo SERVER_STYLE_LOG.'etInp.css'; ?>' />

</head>
<body>
<div id='header'>
<h1>

</h1>
</div>
<div id='content'>

    <button class="inbk" type="submit" name="redirLogin">Login</button>
    <button class="inbk" type="submit" name="redirRegister">Register</button>
    <button class="inbk" type="submit" name="redirRemind">Remind</button>
    <button class="inbk" type="submit" name="redirContact">Contact</button>

</div>
<div id='footer'>

this is the default footer

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If i display `test.php` on localhost directly, `localhost/folder/folder/test.php` - i am geting the right styles (buttons are aligned horizontally), and if i check, they are included in the `head` part.

If i display `test.php` using simple mvc, i get wrong styles (buttons are vertical), and the stylesheet and metatags are included in the `body`

```
ob_start();
$viewData = $this->data; 
include_once( $this->viewTemplPath.$this->file );
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110643/move-style-from-php-to-head  - seems helpfull

Comment: I  have removed all `print_r`, and `echo` statements, which i have used fro debugging. After this, the `head` is in place, thus styles and meta tags are working.

Comment: the `<span>` inside `head`, like  `<head><span id="styles1" class="styles"> <link .... /> </span></head>`  also gives errors, about missing `head`, and misplaced `body`. If you need javascript apply to head, put `class` and `id` inside `link`, do not create wrapping span for this.

Comment: I mean, i had misplaced meta tags and styles, they were not in the `head`, but in the `body` instead.